# Reliable freeware program to search through programming files for words?

Tags: search

I'm looking for a program/application of some sort to download, that will allow me to select multiple files, and search all of them for a phrase or word, on a Windows machine.  For example, I want to search for 'bubblegum' in 100 files, and any files that contain that word somewhere, I want to know what they are.

These could be a wide range of files used by programmers - .asp files, .php files, .NET files, uncompiled java files, etc.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but doesn't notepad++ do this if you use "Find in File"?

If you place the files you want to search through in the same direcotry and then search for 
Directory: C:\fakeplace*.*